Uploading Youtube Videos via Youtube API with "@" attribution in title does not properly create "@" attribution
I am attempting to upload Youtube Videos via Youtube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert). I am able to properly set "#"s which become hyperlinks in the video's title, but "@" attribution remains as plaintext. I have to go into Youtube Studio and re-type the "@" attribution in order for the channel hyperlink to work. Is this intended?
Reproduction steps:

Attempt to upload Youtube video via https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert. Provide Title "This is a test upload #test @google".
Visit Youtube video, the "#test" string will be a hyperlink to https://www.youtube.com/hashtag/test while the "@google" string will just be plaintext. We expect "@google" to be a hyperlink to https://www.youtube.com/@google.
Visit Youtube Studio and modify Title of video. Add "@google". This should create a hypertext string.

